# Obtain P(x)=integrate W(v,x)dv, from the matrix A(Vvalues,Xvalues,W(v,x)) in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, plot, probability-density

OK, first to clarify: I am asking for an algorithm that I could use for my problem please (however to get a Matlab code in addition would be nice). I didn't post any code here, because I don't know how to write an algorithm for this.

The MATLAB matrix `A` has three columns, `v`,`x`,`W(v,x))`, for `v` in the range

```
v_min <= v <= v_max
```

and `x` in the range

```
x_min <= x <= x_max
```

The first two columns have all the different integer combinations of `v` and `x`, the third column has the corresponding value of `W(v,x)`.

E.g. For `v=[-1 0 1]` and `x=[-1 0 1]`, I have -

```
     v  x  W(v,x) 
A =  -1 -1  3 
     -1  0  4 
     -1  1  0 
      0 -1  10 
      0  0  1 
      0  1  25 
      1 -1  2 
      1  0  1 
      1  1  5
```

How do I obtain an approximation for `P(x)=integral W(v,x)dv` from this matrix in Matlab? Clearly, the integral should be replaced effectively by some summation on this matrix, but which?

`W(v,x)` is a phase-space density of a physical system and `P(x)` is the marginal distribution of the position `x`.

Bonus question: How do I plot `W(v,x)` itself with respect to both `v` and `x` (but as something like a heatmap with colours please, not using `scatter3`...)?

Comment: I didn't understand what is `int_v`? Can you clarify it please?

Comment: That mean that P(x) is the integral of W(v,x) over v, from v_min to v_max.

Comment: You need to post what code you have tried and where specifically you're stuck. You have asked at least 2 questions here (integral approximation and 3D plotting), each with a potentially broad answer...

Comment: I don't know what ALGORITHM i should use for this purpose! This is why I don't post a CODE. I The question comes from a physics simulation, I need an idea how to implement this in Matlab please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, we can go this way:

1. For getting integral: there are built-in function `trapz` for getting numeric integral. Now we need to create **function** P(x) - because we need to get `trapz` for current `x`. Here it is:

   ```
   fun = @(x) trapz( A(find(A(:,2)==x),3 ))
   ```

   The `find` function choose indexes of `A` for current `x` and then uses `trapz` to get integral.
   That is anonymous function returns integral value of `W(v,x)dv` for current value of `x`:

   ```
   fun(-1)
   ans =
      12.5000
   ```
2. Second question: about plotting.
   We can use `surf` function to get 3D surface. But this function uses matrices of coordinates, not vectors, so lets `reshape` view of `A` matrix:

   ```
   v = reshape( A(:,1), [3,3])
   x = reshape( A(:,2), [3,3])
   W = reshape( A(:,3), [3,3])
   surf(v,x,W)
   ```

   We use `[3, 3]` here for this: 
   I want to plot `v` as X axis, `x` as Y axis and `W` as Z. `v` has 3 specific values and `x` has 3 too. So we need to create 3x3 matrix of values! 
   [image]
   That's not very beautiful in due to little amount of points, but I hope it is what you want.

Comment: Can you clarify about the reshape pls: in [3,3], the first '3' on the left is because of the three numbers [-1,0,1], or because A has 3 columns? What about the second '3' on the right?

Comment: @user1611107 I use `[3, 3]` because of three numbers [-1, 0, 1]. I add some info to answer.
Hope its helpful!